# How to define ng-src based on condition?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
```

I need the value in data-ng-src to be different according to a condition.

If image.IsAdvert is **true** then:

```
data-ng-src="{{image.Url}}"
```

if the image.IsAdvert is **false** then

```
data-ng-src="file/{{image.Url}}"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use conditional operator:-

```
<img ng-src="{{image.isAdvert?image.Url:('file/' + image.Url)}}"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could return it from a function on the scope:

```
data-ng-src="{{getUrl(image)}}"
```

and

```
$scope.getUrl = function(image){
  return image.isAdvert ? image.Url : "file/" + image.Url;
}
```