# angular dynamic ng-src based on data value

Tags: angularjs

I have double checked the 2 threads which are close to the same topic before asking,

1. [How to define ng-src based on condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264821/how-to-define-ng-src-based-on-condition)
2. [Conditionally change img src based on model data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999659/conditionally-change-img-src-based-on-model-data)

   but i am not sure these answers are "best practice" - such as defining `true`-`false` statements in the `{{}}` of HTML.

On to my question:
I am trying to load an image based on an array of objects, such that when `Key:Value pair "IconOne = 1"` it loads `icon1`, `"IconTwo = 2"` it loads `icon2`.  The Value is generated from a JSON file so that IconOne can also be 1,2,3,or 4 so it's never consistent.

My current HTML code is:

```
<ul class="snowSnapText" ng-repeat="mtns in mtnsArray | orderBy:'-lastSnow' | limitTo: 5 ">
      <li><img alt="ski resort logos" class="mtnLogo" ng-src="{{mtns.logoUrl}}"></li>
      <li class="snowSnapName">{{mtns.name}}</li>
      <li class="snowSnapInches">{{mtns.lastSnow}}"</li>
      <li class="snowSnapDeg">{{mtns.hi}}&deg</li>
      <li class="snowSnapIcon"><img alt="weather icon" ng-src="{{getIcons()}}">{{mtns.IconOne}}</li>
```

My current JS controller looks like:

```
$scope.getIcons = function(){
if($scope.mtnsArray.IconOne == 1){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
}
else if($scope.mtnsArray.IconOne == 2){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
}
else if($scope.mtnsArray.IconOne == 3){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
}
else {
    return '../img/icon_snow.png';
}
};
```

I am able to get the `ELSE` icon to appear in my page for ALL my `NG-REPEAT` lines, but I feel a bit stuck for some reason and am hoping a new set of eyes can help.

Because my JSON data is being pushed into an Object Constructor from a Factory, what is the best way to access the IconOne value in my Function?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your `$scope.mtnsArray.IconOne`  `mtnsArray` is an `array`  not an `object` ?

when it is an array you cant take the values using a dot ( . )

re write your code like this :

use     `ng-src="{{getIcons(mtns)}}`

```
$scope.getIcons = function(mtns){
 if(mtns.IconOne == 1){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
 }
 else if(mtns.IconOne == 2){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
 }
 else if(mtns.IconOne == 3){
    return '../img/icon_sunny.png';
 }
 else {
    return '../img/icon_snow.png';
 }
};
```

or do the following at page load itself

```
 for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.mtnsArray.length ; i++ ){

    if($scope.mtnsArray[i].IconOne == 1){
        $scope.mtnsArray[i].imgURL =  '../img/icon_sunny.png';
    }
    else if($scope.mtnsArray[i].IconOne == 2){
        $scope.mtnsArray[i].imgURL =  '../img/icon_sunny.png';
    }
    else if($scope.mtnsArray[i].IconOne == 3){
        $scope.mtnsArray[i].imgURL =  '../img/icon_sunny.png';
    }
    else {
        $scope.mtnsArray[i].imgURL =  '../img/icon_snow.png';
    }
}
```

and use `ng-src="{{mtns.imgURL}}`